# NHibernate and operator overloading

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
public class Version
{
    public byte Major { get; set; }
    public byte Minor { get; set; }
    public short Build { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }

    private long NumVersion
    {
        //get {}
        //set {}
        //Some logic that make Int64 number that represents this verion
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to be able to write queries like

`Where<Product>(t=>t.Version > new Version(1,2,0,0))`

In Product table I store only Int64 NumVersion field, so Version property is mapped as component, and currently I query it like `Where<Product>(t=>t.Version.NumVersion > new Version(1,2,0,0).NumVersion)`

In C# I can 1. Overload comparison operators, 2. Make it implicitly casted to long like:

```
public static implicit operator long(Version v)
{
    return v.NumVersion;
}
```

This will allow me to compare Version objects, but how to make NHibernate understand this and generate proper SQL ?

Comment: You will have to patch nhibernate to teach him how to translate version comparing into sql somewhere around this area: http://bit.ly/p3dkXy ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. You will either have to explicitly write comparisons for each `Version` component or filter on the client side.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant ? (NHibernate 5.2.5)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
class p
{
    private p() { }

    public static p Version { get { return new p(); } }

    public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> operator >(p left, Version version)
    {
        return product => product.Version.NumVersion > version.NumVersion;
    }
    ...
}


Where<Product>(p.Version > new Version(1,2,0,0))
```